# Getting more images to the left of the slide

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve multiple images in two rows. However, it aligns properly up to 9 images; however, after the 9 images, the next images show up in the third row. I want to keep it at 2 rows. How can I achieve this? D:
I am trying to make it look like the gallery portion of websites like zillow.com and hotels.com where the user posts their images and it gets uploaded. not all of them will have that many images but just in case. I don't want there to be a max.

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 165px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.grid-container>div {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.item1 {
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}

.detailed-gallery-outer {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

.detailed-gallery-inner {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.detailed-gallery-tmb {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}

.detailed-gallery {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 1140px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="detailed-gallery">
  <div class="arrow-left">
    <div class="arrow-left-small">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="detailed-gallery-outer">
      <div class="detailed-gallery-inner">
        <div class="grid-container">
          <div class="item1"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_forest.jpg" alt="office1" width="250" height="340" /></div>
          <div class="item2"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_forest.jpg" alt="office2" width="250" height="165" /></div>
          <div class="item3"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_forest.jpg" alt="office3" width="250" height="165" /></div>
          <div class="item4"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_forest.jpg" alt="office4" width="250" height="165" /></div>
          <div class="item5"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_forest.jpg" alt="office5" width="250" height="165" /></div>
          <div class="item6"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_forest.jpg" alt="office6" width="250" height="165" /></div>
          <div class="item7"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_forest.jpg" alt="office7" width="250" height="165" /></div>
          <div class="item8"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_forest.jpg" alt="office8" width="250" height="165" /></div>
          <div class="item9"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_forest.jpg" alt="office9" width="250" height="165" /></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="arrow-right">
    <div class="arrow-right-small">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can post the JS code as well but I don't think that is the issue.

Comment: Perhaps look into using Carousel? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/

Answer (score 0):

Just delete `grid-row: 1/ 3;`

FROM

```
    .item1 {
    grid-row: 1 / 3;
}
```

TO

```
    .item1 {
    grid-row: 1 / 2;
}
```

Moreover, you have to adjust the width of the container. Either make it `100%` or change to a with which is bigger than `5x250=1250`.

Check [this](https://codepen.io/aydinbagiyev/pen/EdNJye) P.S. I have added 1 extra image of same 9.

Comment: Oh, and another note, I want the first image to be larger than the rest.

Comment: This is normal because you have 5 images in each row and each has 250px width. With a simple math 5x250=1250, but sadly you have set the width of the galary container to 1140 px.